# UIlabel layer.cornerRadius not working in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uilabel, cornerradius

I'm currently looking at a UILabel with the property `addMessageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;` On a device with iOS 7.0 installed, it has rounded corners. On a device with iOS 7.1 installed, it does not have rounded corners.

Is this just a bug with iOS 7.1?

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Set the property `clipsToBounds` to true

```
addMessageLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Not sure why you didn't have to do that on iOS 7 but have to iOS 7.1, but it worked! Thanks

Comment: This is indeed weird!

Comment: No, not weird...just "progress"...<humf>, it seems that UILabel's clipsToBounds is now defaulting to FALSE like most other UIViews. Apple's probably trying to make stuffs more consistent. I too just had the same issue.

Comment: Is this documented in the iOS 7.1 release notes as a breaking change or is this just another 'surprise' that they threw in for us?

Comment: @ChristopherKing i couldn't find documentation on this, but this worked in my scenario too, surprise I guess :)

Comment: = clip subviews with storyboards.

Comment: @imankazemayni the post is old, it was answered in Objective C. Objective C has YES/NO for true/false, I am updating my answer as well

Comment: it was better if your old answer exist. one for objective C and another for swift ... tnks

Answer (score 67):

I think the best way to set corner radius is:

[image]

and be sure the "Clip Subviews" is checked:

[image]

Checking "Clip Subviews" is equal to the code `addMessageLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;`.

Comment: Definitely, the easiest way

Comment: This is the best way. Tested with ios 8+ and xcode 7.2.

Comment: If anyone came here looking for this and it didnt work: if you put the property "cornerRadius" it will work on iOS10+. On iOS9 it has to be "layer.cornerRadius"

Comment: clipToBounds can also be set in the User Defined Runtime Attributes (the same as the layer.cornerRadius): it should be key Path: clipsToBounds, type: Boolean, value: true

Answer (score 31):

Try the followings,

```
[[addMessageLabel layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[[addMessageLabel layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];

//or
[addMessageLabel setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
addMessageLable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
addMessageLable.layer.masksToBounds = true

//or
addMessageLable.layer.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 5):

My issue was a bit different.

While I *did* do  `btn.clipsToBounds = true`

I wasn't setting doing:

```
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

Because I had different screen sizes. Instead I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961794/5175709) answer and did:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    seeMoreButton.layer.cornerRadius = seeMoreButton.bounds.size.height / 2
}
```

It wasn't working because I forgot to add `super.layoutSubviews()`. The correct code is:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    seeMoreButton.layer.cornerRadius = seeMoreButton.bounds.size.height / 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. Only this answer worked for me. Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the below one and i got an successful output.

```
yourlabelname.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
[yourlabelname setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Is there something else which is stopping you?

Comment: Before iOS 7.1, `clipsToBounds` was defaulted to `YES`, so the line `[yourlabelname setClipsToBounds:YES];` wasn't in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //works perfect in Swift 2.0 for a circular or round image          


@IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    //Make sure the width and height are same
            self.theImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.theImage.frame.size.width / 2
            self.theImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            self.theImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            self.theImage.clipsToBounds = true

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourlabelname.layer.cornerRadius = yourlabelname.frame.size.width/2;
[yourlabelname setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Make sure you are checking with appropriate Deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following Code as extension for UIView

```
//// Story board Extra Feature for create border radius, border width and border Color
extension UIView {
    /// corner radius
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

After that you will get the following attributes in interface builder itself.!

[image]